# Export different list to 2 files of CSV using C#

Tags: c#, csv

There are 2 different list of objects, need to export 2 different files as .csv and return the same using C#. 
   Please help me to find the optimistic way to implement the same.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use already implemented libraries, for example:

- [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper)
- [File Helpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/)

or any other you like. They usually already support functions that work with a lists of a data.

Comment: Can you please explain for handling multiple files using helpers. Any samples?

Comment: @SUBRA: it depends how you handle them: if you have a list1 to put in File1, list2 into File2. Just write them down using library.

Answer (score 1):

Simple code how to save list of object into csv file, not yet tested but you can get the idea:

```
var properties = typeof(YourModel).GetProperties();

string headerLine = string.Join(",",
                typeof(YourModel).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name));

var dataLines = yourModellist.Select(item =>
            string.Join(",", properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(item, null))));

var allLines = new[] { headerLine }.Concat(dataLines);

File.WriteAllLines("your csv file", allLines);
```

Comment: This is actually for how to write and return one file.. i need return multiple files or in zip which has 2csvs..

Comment: @SUBRA: well, just the code how to write, to return 2 files, you can call this code twice

Comment: will it return 2 files for one click?

Comment: @SUBRA: in one click, you can call twice

Comment: Sample please.. ? page should not get refresh.. on click of the button, it should be able to return 2 files

Comment: @SUBRA: you need to update your question for more detail, seem you want to download file from web